# How to create tables in Ignite using spring boot java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, spring-data, ignite

I was implementing ignite using spring boot. I have configured my ignite instance using java only. I have also created two entity. I am able to use basic crud commands of ignite but I can't write my own sql query to query the tables. It's show IgniteException: table not found.

Item.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
@Data
public class Item implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2974414641088735500L;

    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    private String itemCode;

    @QuerySqlField
    private String areaCode;

    @QuerySqlField
    private String zoneCode;

    @QuerySqlField
    private Long demand;

    @QuerySqlField
    private Long inventory;

    @QuerySqlField
    private Double doi;

    @QuerySqlField
    private Long qtyToReachDoi;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "itemCache")
public interface IgniteItemRepository extends IgniteRepository<Item,String> {
    String queryForItemsWithDemandGT10 = "select * from item_cache i where i.demand>10";
    @Query(value = queryForItemsWithDemandGT10)
    public List<Item> getItemWithDemandGT10();
}
```

ServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class IgniteItemServiceImpl implements IgniteItemService {

    @Autowired
    IgniteItemRepository repo;

    @Override
    public Mono<Item> saveBulkItemToCache(MultipartFile file) {
        return Mono.create(consumer -> {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                InputStream in = file.getInputStream();
                objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,false);
                List<Item> itemList = objectMapper.readValue( in, new TypeReference<List<Item>>(){});
                itemList.forEach(e->repo.save(String.valueOf(Math.random()),e));
            } catch (Exception ex ) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public List<Item> viewItemList() {
        List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        repo.findAll().forEach(e->itemList.add(e));
        return itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Item> viewItemWithDemand() {
        return repo.getItemWithDemandGT10();
    }
}
```

Ignite Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIgniteRepositories
public class ApacheIgniteConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Ignite igniteInstance(@Autowired IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration) {
        igniteConfiguration.setAutoActivationEnabled(true);
        igniteConfiguration.setActiveOnStart(true);
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(igniteConfiguration);
        ignite.active(true);
        return ignite;
    }

    @Bean(name = "igniteConfiguration")
    public IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration() {
        IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();
        igniteConfiguration.setIgniteInstanceName("igniteTest");
        igniteConfiguration.setClientMode(false);
        igniteConfiguration.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true); //to allow any client to put node on cluster
        igniteConfiguration.setLocalHost("127.0.0.1");

        TcpDiscoverySpi tcpDiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
        TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
        ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
        tcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
        tcpDiscoverySpi.setLocalPort(47500);
        // Changing local port range. This is an optional action.
        tcpDiscoverySpi.setLocalPortRange(9);
        //tcpDiscoverySpi.setLocalAddress("localhost");
        igniteConfiguration.setDiscoverySpi(tcpDiscoverySpi);

        TcpCommunicationSpi communicationSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
        communicationSpi.setLocalAddress("localhost");
        communicationSpi.setLocalPort(48100);
        communicationSpi.setSlowClientQueueLimit(1000);
        igniteConfiguration.setCommunicationSpi(communicationSpi);


        DataStorageConfiguration storageConfiguration  = new DataStorageConfiguration();
        DataRegionConfiguration regionConfiguration = new DataRegionConfiguration();
        regionConfiguration.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        regionConfiguration.setName("igniteRegion");

        storageConfiguration.setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration(regionConfiguration);
        igniteConfiguration.setDataStorageConfiguration(storageConfiguration);
        igniteConfiguration.setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfiguration());

        return igniteConfiguration;

    }

    @Bean(name = "cacheConfiguration")
    public CacheConfiguration[] cacheConfiguration() {
        List<CacheConfiguration> cacheConfigurations = new ArrayList<>();
        CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration();
        cacheConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
        cacheConfiguration.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
        cacheConfiguration.setName("employee");
        cacheConfiguration.setWriteThrough(false);
        cacheConfiguration.setReadThrough(false);
        cacheConfiguration.setWriteBehindEnabled(false);
        cacheConfiguration.setBackups(1);
        cacheConfiguration.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
        cacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(Long.class,Employee.class);

        CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration1 = new CacheConfiguration();
        cacheConfiguration1.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
        cacheConfiguration1.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
        cacheConfiguration1.setName("itemCache");
        cacheConfiguration1.setWriteThrough(false);
        cacheConfiguration1.setReadThrough(false);
        cacheConfiguration1.setWriteBehindEnabled(false);
        cacheConfiguration1.setBackups(1);
        cacheConfiguration1.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
        cacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(String.class,Item.class);

        cacheConfigurations.add(cacheConfiguration);
        cacheConfigurations.add(cacheConfiguration1);

        return cacheConfigurations.toArray(new CacheConfiguration[cacheConfigurations.size()]);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to find SQL table for type: Item
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.typeName(GridQueryProcessor.java:2898) ~[ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySql(GridQueryProcessor.java:2548) ~[ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.query(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:799) ~[ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.query(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:412) ~[ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.springdata22.repository.query.IgniteRepositoryQuery.execute(IgniteRepositoryQuery.java:121) ~[ignite-spring-data_2.2-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.getItemWithDemandGT10(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.getItemWithDemandGT10(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.ignite.service.impl.IgniteItemServiceImpl.viewItemWithDemand(IgniteItemServiceImpl.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.ignite.controller.IgniteItemController.viewItemWithDemand(IgniteItemController.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure caches/tables using the Cache API then: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/configuration-overview

Also, watch a recording of this workshop:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Jc-6yQiq-Io

Or join a training session to learn even more:
https://www.gridgain.com/products/services/training/apache-ignite-spring-boot-and-spring-data-development

Comment: How to sync ignite cache key value pair with ignite sql table?

Comment: If types match then anything put in cache via key/value APIs will be available as table rows and vice versa.